# HTML,CSS Divs Position is Fine without Contents but after adding H1 and P tags, Position Messes Up

Tags: html, css

I have an issue with my Code in which I have 3 Divs, (1 Is a Large one and 2nd one is for the blank space between the 1st and 3rd div, The 3rd div is a small one)

All 3 Contain nothing

Without h1 and p tags, The Position (On my Screen) of Divs is Fine (Desired)
But after adding the tags, The Position changes (Divs go down and do weird things)

Code Without Tags (Might only work on a 1366x768 screen)

```css
@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700';

body {
 font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
 background-color: #0C0C0C;
}
.container {
 color: black;
 display: inline-block;
 margin-left: 4%;
}
.frame1 {
 display: inline-block;
 color: white;
 background-color: #0C0C0C;
 width: 864px;
 height: 535px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 border: solid 3px white;
 margin-left: 36px;
}
.space {
 background-color: #0C0C0C;
 width: 50px;
 height: 425px;
 margin-top: 4%;
 border-radius: 5px;
 display: inline-block;
 padding-top: 125px;
}
.frame2 {
 display: inline-block;
 background-color: #0C0C0C;
 width: 350px;
 height: 535px;
 margin-top: 4%;
 border-radius: 5px;
 border: solid 3px white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Testing</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
 </head>
 <body>
   <div class="frame1">
    
   </div>
   <div class="space">
   </div>
   <div class="frame2">
    
   </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

I do nothing more than add H1 and P tags in the divs and the position messes up

Help is appreciated

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you add a second snippet that illustrates where you're putting the `h1` and `p` tags?

Comment: Remove default margin and padding from the h1 and p tags perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `vertical-align: top` to the inline-block elements:

```
.frame1, .frame2, .space {
   vertical-align: top;
}
```

You may then need to play around with your 4% top margins to get them aligned along the top (I noticed `.frame1` is missing the top margin).

Comment: Thank you for this,

Comment: No problem. If you feel this answer solved your issue, please consider marking it "accepted". If not, I'd be happy to help more.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to add `float:left;` to each of the divs.
Also it would be helpful if you can provide a text that you want to insert or how it should look like as final target.
'Cause adding an float - divs don't fall.

Answer (score 0):

```
.space {
 width: 50px;
 display: inline-block;
 }
```

you don't need space height and padding. your works fine. 
[image: SEE it works on my screen]

and you already fix your frame width so it will be break when screen size 1310px
Happy coding